# binding DateTime from access to C# Form

Tags: c#, ms-access, datetime-format

I try to show my date time field from Access DB into C# by using `DataGridView`,
at Access table the date time Field show the current date time `Now()` with `ShortDate` Format...
looks perfect in Access,
but at DataGridView in C# Form its shown with time (hours/minutes/am,pm)

[ScreenShot for Access Table in design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttBO0.png)

[ScreenShot for Access Table in Table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz1a1.png)

[DataGridView At C# Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsqOg.png)

How can i show the datetime at datagrid as this format ("MM/dd/yyyy") ? exactly like Access Table dtnow Field ??

Comment: Set [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of the cell style. For example, `dataGridView1.Column[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy"`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Its Working Thank you

Comment: @RezaAghaei, sounds like could write a valid answer to this question.